# What are advantages of using SQL Server Database Project in VS 2013?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013

What are advantages of using SQL Server Database Project in VS 2013?
Currently I dont use this on my project, I am generate script from SQL Server Management.
Should I move to Database Project? How complicated is?

Comment: Don't understand what you mean. Do you have a project in SSMS today and want to know advantages of moving it to VS? Or don't you save your work at all today ("I am generate script") and want to know if there are advantages to start using a project.

Comment: Sorry about my English.
I maintain a database through Microsoft SQL Server Management (Add new table, delete table, add some data, add new column … and so on )
Then when I change what I want, I generate script through Microsoft SQL Server Management with all my changes.
Everyone else(at same project) can then execute my script to get all changes.
I want to know what are advantages/disadvantages to have Database project, and maintain DB through Visual studio 2013.
Is this clear enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many advantage of sql project.

1.Easily deployable in any conditions.
2.You can view history of db objects
3.You can maitain all db objects under on roof.

Effectively, a database project converts all of the objects in your database (table designs, stored procedures) into text files -- text files that can be searched, modified and stored in source control just like your code files. A database project also includes designers for working with these files. Visual Studio cross-references those files to give you a higher level of IntelliSense support for working with stored procedures than you'll ever get in SQL Server Management Studio.

You also get a staging database where you can make your changes before updating your production or development database and a schema comparison tool for determining, after the fact, what changes you've made. Effectively, you get an isolated database environment for trying out database changes.